# BeanPostProcessor with @Bean annotation not working

Tags: spring, spring-ioc

I'm trying to create a `BeanPostProcessor` for registering some values to a Map.

The `BeanPostProcessor` works fine if I'm create the bean instance via xml definition, but if I change the bean definition to `@Configuration` it is not working.

PostProcessor

```
public class InstantiationTracingBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

  public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
      return bean;
  }

  public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
      System.out.println("Bean '" + beanName );
      return bean;
  }
}
```

Bean Configuration

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class Configuration {
    @Bean
    public @Qualifier("InstantiationTracingBeanPostProcessor")
    InstantiationTracingBeanPostProcessor activitiConfigurationBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new InstantiationTracingBeanPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Component scan Configuration

```
<context:component-scan base-package="xyz.config"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

The application just hangs if I use the above configuration. But if I use xml based configuration as given below it works fine.

```
<bean class="xyz.bean.InstantiationTracingBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: And Can I see your Main Method?

Comment: @harish.raj It is a web-app

Comment: Which Spring Version do you use?

Comment: Can you please show the configuration where you load up the bean definitions in your Configuration class

Comment: @BijuKunjummen The configuration class is in the component scan path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got a solution to this after asking another question in [spring forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?133596-BeanPostProcessor-with-Bean-annotation-not-working).

The bean factory method should be defined as a `static method` to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

I thought the way to do this was to annotate your `BeanPostProcessor` with `Component`:

```
@Component
public class InstantiationTracingBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    //...
}
```

Which would be automatically handled by Spring during component scan (so no need to add a `@Bean`-annotated method to the configuration).